# How can I post a JSON object using a Dictionary?

Tags: json, vb.net

Here is the JSON content that needs to be posted.

```
{
 "getcart": {
              "version": "1.0",
              "account": "6566",
              "username": "112",
              "password": "xxxxxxxx",
              "cartid": "57044d79",
} }
```

**Code:**

```
Dim jsonPost As New JsonPost("https://www.example.aspx")
Dim dictData As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)

dictData.Add("version", "1.0")
dictData.Add("account", "6566")
dictData.Add("username", "112")
dictData.Add("password", "xxxxxxxx")
dictData.Add("cartid", "57044d79")

Dim json As JObject = JObject.Parse(JsonPost.postData(dictData))
Dim response As String = JsonPost.postData(dictData)
MsgBox(response)
```

The error I'm getting:

> Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path'',line 0 postion 0

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't do it using the dictionary. But I was able to post it as a string.

The main issue was declaring a JSON string that contains an object in Visual Basic. Here is how I did it:

```
    Dim JsonData As String = "{'getcart':{
                                        'version':'1.0',
                                        'account':'6566',
                                        'username':'112',
                                        'password':'xxxxxxxx',
                                        'cartid':'57044d79',
                                         }}"

    Dim Uri As String = "https://www."
    Dim data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonData)
    Dim result_post = SendRequest(New Uri(Uri), data, "application/json", "POST")
    MsgBox(result_post)

Private Function SendRequest(uri As Uri, jsonDataBytes As Byte(), contentType As String, method As String) As String
    Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri)
    req.ContentType = contentType
    req.Method = method
    req.ContentLength = jsonDataBytes.Length


    Dim stream = req.GetRequestStream()
    stream.Write(jsonDataBytes, 0, jsonDataBytes.Length)
    stream.Close()

    Dim response = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()

    Dim reader As New StreamReader(response)
    Dim res = reader.ReadToEnd()
    reader.Close()
    response.Close()

    Return res
End Function
```